# Extbase: How to switch a CE in Backend (analog FE -> layout)

Tags: typo3, extbase

In a custom extbase content element extension i can use the layout field (appearance -> layout) to switch the fluid template in the Frontend.

But what if I need to switch the complete content element in backend? 
For example I want to change the labels or the fields in the backend.
How can U do this?
Or another example:
I have an irre link element, where the user decides between an item for text or thumbnail links. How to realize this in my extension?

Does anybody have an existing example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TCA definition you can use 'type' definitions. One of the fields is defined as type field and when the BE user changes the value other fields, palettes and labels can be shown.

[types documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Types/Index.html#types-section)

As you can see in the [documentation for the 'showitem' property](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Types/Index.html#showitem) you can even change the labels for a field when a different type is selected.

For examples you can look inside the TYPO3 core. One example is the [TCA for pages](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/TCA/pages.php) which has a lot of types, one for each doktype.

---

Regarding the IRRE question, you can show and hide fields using the property [displayCond](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond). If you need to reload the form because a displayCond depends on the value of a field you can force that with the [onChange](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Flex/Index.html?highlight=onchange#t3datastructure-extensions-for-tceforms) property.
Note that in TYPO3 v7 the onChange/displayCond combination does NOT work if both are inside a section. It works if the onChange is outside the section and the displayCond is inside a section.
This works in 6.2 and again in 8.

Comment: But for the IRRE case, it is not possible to place the displayCond. select box in the parent ce, in order to show and hide a field in the IRRE level?
It works only in the same level.. selectbox in the IRRE level->shows or hides fields in the IRRE level.

Comment: Sorry, I started to find a solution for FlexForm sections when I read IRRE. In IRRE items each item is a record of its own; just related to the main record. So, you could also define a type field in the records you edit inline and determine the fields with that type field. Haven't tried it just now as I have no extension with this setup on my system at the moment.